# How to get clicked value of header to other component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components, one is compo1 and other is compo2, so when I click a div tag "Clickprint" on compo1,I should get the value into compo2. compo1 is the common component like header,so it will be there in each component.I am getting this error(Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setId')when I click "Clickprint" div". Here is the code below.

### compo1.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,props } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Compo1 = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    
    const handlePrint = () => {
        const event ="hi"
        console.log(event)
        // your logic and use setId from props.
        // This is just an example.
        props.setId(event.target.value);
     }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="">
                <div onClick={handlePrint}>Clickprint</div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export default Compo1;

compo2.js
--------
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
    
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Compo2 = (props) => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
        const id = props.id;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="banner d-flex">
            <compo2 id={id} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export default Comp2;
```

Comment: Hey, your question is not clear. Please make it more clear and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: When I click a div tag on compo1,I should get the value into compo2 component.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but the error is thrown because you are calling props.setId while props is not defined. You probably just want to call setId to update the state of your component.

Also, if you trying to get some data from the click event, you can get them from the handlePrint event parameter.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect,props } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Compo1 = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    
    const handlePrint = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
     
         setId(event.target.getAttribute("value"));
     }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="">
                <div onClick={handlePrint} value="someValue">Clickprint</div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
export default Compo1;
```

Comment: compo1 is my header component , when I route to compo2 and  click on div tag of compo1 I should get some value of compo1 to compo2 , I  tried this code but it is not working.

Comment: Which value you want to get from compo1? And where do you want it to store in compo2?

Comment: when my routing will be on compo2 page, I want to get const event ="hi" from compo1 onclick of div tag and want to show it to console of compo2